# Does NSZombieEnabled only work on Objective-C code?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, nszombie, nszombieenabled

In an Objective-C project, if I am incorporating some C code, does the environmental variable NSZombieEnabled help me debug accidentally de-allocated region which I've done with C code, or does it only work for the Objective-C part?

Comment: thanks for editing the grammar and the cases. I should be more careful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only works for Objective-C objects. Instead of dying, the objects turn into zombies which will complain on attempt to send them any message. Since plain memory cannot receive messages, this mechanism makes no sense for it.

You need Valgrind or similar tools for generic memory debugging.

Comment: I see. I was only suspecting this when I began to get weird result.